# Consolidating cpvc elbows out of water heater

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, cpvc

I've just noticed a crack in one of the 90 elbows coming out of our water heater, which I am going to replace. But for some reason, the water makes 3 turns before going to the rest of the house. I know this creates extra friction, but I'm new to plumbing, so could this be set up for a valid reason? Or can I safely cut out all 3 turns and replace them with a single elbow?

[image]

Comment: Is that a weird artifact in the picture, or is there a big gash in the heating duct at the left edge of the picture, just to the left of that lower elbow?

Comment: @FreeMan that's actually the corner of a wooden shelf. I can see how scary that would look though hah

Comment: Ah! Now that you've described it, I can see that. Sure didn't look like that at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly what I would do for the reason you stated and it will look better.  That appears it may be above your hot water heater, if so consider adding a union in the line.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct that this is above the water heater. I'll verify before i replace the joint, but i believe there is a union where the cpvc meets the copper pipe.